# Interquartile ranges

Tags: r

```
poll_iqr <- as.data.frame(sapply(pollutants, IQR, na.rm = TRUE))
names(poll_iqr)<-'IQR'
poll_est_iqr <- cbind(poll_est, poll_iqr)
```

I would like to get the 5-95% interquartile range for this loop sapply function. Any ideas how I can change it from the 25-75% default. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use the fucntion `quantile` and substract it yourself. See `?quantile` it is also suggested in documentaion at `?IQR`. It is the only way since IQR doesnt take that sort of argument. It is so defined in statistics